# How to create service listening to the clipboard

Tags: android, service

I create service that lauch barcode scanner (it´s configure to save scanned result to clipboard) and I need to listen to the clipboard to save it and diplayed dialog message during the scanning. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When ever a code is scanned, save it into clipboard and afterwards broadcast a message. That broadcasted message should be handled by your service to know when it has to read the clipboard. Once your service receives that particular broadcast, access the clipboard in your service as below:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: But I lauch an aplication the Barcode scanner...it´s not mine. Is there some way to continously scann an clipboard...in android less then 3.0

Comment: Yes, then you need to observe if the contents inside clipboard are changed. See this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ClipboardSample.html

Comment: OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() is avaible since API 11(Android 3.0.x), I use api 7...Any other way?

Comment: then use an infinite-loop in a separate thread inside your service to keep checking the Clipboard. You may use Handler or CountDownTimer to achieve this too